# Unable to install Salesforce CLI

Tags: cli

I just recieved my work laptop and I am trying to install my salesforce DX. I have downloaded Salesforce CLI but not able to install it. The installation wizard is opening a popup box stating that not able to write Output folder:
C:\Program Files\sfdx
Output folder: C:\Program Files\sfdx\bin
**Can't write: C:\Program Files\sfdx\bin\sf**

It asking me to either abort or skip the file. What do I do ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the installer as Administrator (right-click, Run As Administrator). If you don't have Administrator permissions, you can try installing [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/download/), then installing the CLI via `npm install --global sfdx-cli`.

Comment: Hi. I tried to run as administrator. It is asking for credentials of IT user name and It password. I dont have those. This is a work laptop

Comment: @BashSalesforce Like I said, you can install NodeJS as a non-administrator (in most cases), the install the NPM version of sfdx-cli. If your laptop is *really* locked down, then you'll have to have IT install for you via GPO.